# Who was killed in the sentence below?

Tags: meaning, charles-dickens, a-tale-of-two-cities

From Charles Dickens's *A Tale of Two Cities*:

> The highwayman in the dark was a City tradesman in the light, and,
> being recognised and challenged by his fellow-tradesman whom he
> stopped in his character of the Captain, gallantly shot him through
> the head and rode away.

Who was shot? The highwayman (city tradesman) or his fellow-tradesman?

Comment: From our sister-site, English language for learners, the same question but with a terrible non-descriptive title: [what does this phrase mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52363/what-does-this-phrase-mean)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's  his fellow-tradesman who died.

> [The highwayman in the dark was a City tradesman in the light]{1}, ***and***, *[being recognised and challenged by his fellow-tradesman whom he stopped in his character of 'the Captain',]*{2} [gallantly shot him through the head and rode away]{3}.

{2} is a long interruption. If we eliminate it, it is easier to discern the independent clauses that are connected by ***and***, sharing the same subject (*the highwayman*):

> The highwayman in the dark was a City tradesman in the light, ***and*** (...) gallantly shot him through the head and rode away.

The sentence does not make sense without {2} because it contains the object of the verb *shot* (his fellow-tradesman), so I only wrote the sentence without it for the sake of clarity: now it becomes clear that the highwayman shot his fellow who recognised him and challenged him.

This is an excerpt of Charles Dickens's *A Tale of Two Cities* and it tells a story inspired from an account in the Annual Register of 1775, where the events have, however, a different end:

> Mr. Brower, a print-cutter, near Aldersgate-Street, was attacked on the road to Enfield by a single highwayman, whom he recollected to be a tradesman in the city; he accordingly called him by his name, when the robber shot himself through the head. ([dickens.stanford.edu](http://dickens.stanford.edu/tale/issue1_gloss3.html))

---

PS: Note that *the Captain* is the "role" this highwayman took when he would go robbing:

> In *A Tale of Two Cities*, ***the Captain*** is a *highwayman who robs English coach travelers*. He's only mentioned twice at the beginning of the novel, once in chapter one of book one and once in chapter two. ([Study.com](https://homework.study.com/explanation/who-is-the-captain-in-a-tale-of-two-cities.html))

Comment: In the [original excerpt](https://www.weblitera.com/book/?id=160&lng=1&l=), “the captain” has quotes enclosing it.